# OCR for Photo IDs?

Tags: contacts, extension, import, images

I would like to set up an instance of CiviCRM to help independent candidates register to run for office in Indonesia, and one requirement here (like many other countries) is that a candidate has to gather signatories to petition their way onto the ballot. As proof of an individual's signature here, the candidate also has to collect a copy of their valid, government-issued photo ID.

What I would like to do is to allow supporters to essentially attach a photo of their ID to their profile, and then use OCR to verify the data they have entered matches with what is on their actual ID.

Has anyone come across any good tools for doing so? Abbyy.com seems to have some good cloud-based OCR tools, but not sure how hard it might be to integrate these with CiviCRM.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cividesk](https://www.cividesk.com) has written a business card scanner extension: https://www.cividesk.com/blog/post/scan-business-cards-civicrm.  They can speak to specifics.

To write an extension that uses the ABBYY OCR seems like it wouldn't be too difficult, based on [this code sample](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/blob/master/PHP/abbyy_php_example.php).